# Como encuentro el Server Name para SQL Server Management Studio 2017 RC1

Tags: sql-server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito establecer una conección con el SQL Server, pero no puedo conseguir mi `Server Name`. Alguien sabe como conseguir el `instance` para el `SQL Server V17.0 RC1`?

Comment: Está instalado en el mismo PC? o es un servidor independiente?

Comment: Está en el mismo PC

Comment: Sería bueno que aclares si estás intentando conectarte desde el mismo equipo donde está instalado o desde otro diferente

Comment: Hola, yo formateé e instalé el sql managment studio 2018 y tengo el mismo problema. Quiero conertarme al servidor local para crear una base de datos de manera local. Alguien sabe como conectarse? Me aparece el mismo problema.

Answer (score 1):

Has probado en nombre de servidor con (local) o localhost o con el punto . ? Mira en los servicios que se están ejecutando que tendrás ahí el nombre de la instancia (servicio sql server), el predeterminado suele ser MSSQLSERVER y si le has cambiado el nombre de la instancia suele ser nombremaquina\nombreinstancia. Fíjate también que esté levantado el servicio

Answer (score 0):

Si te da igual el nombre que la IP, abriendo una ventana de terminal en el servidor puedes ejecutar este comando `ipconfig` y te devuelve la dirección IP de ese equipo (el servidor). Luego solo es poner la IP en el cliente sql y listo.

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que el servicio SQL Browser se esté ejecutando y en el configuration manager confirma que tienes activos los protocolos sobre los que te vas a conectar al servidor.

[[image: Ver imagen anexa]

Answer (score 0):

Debes entrar al MMC (SQL Server 2017 Configuration Manager) y en SQL Server vas a ver el nombre de la instancia de tu servidor local, allí presionas propiedades y vas a ver tu HostName y tu instancia,

Para abrir el MMC puedes escribir mmc desde buscar de windows o presionar ctrl+r

Tambien puedes entrar escribiendo:

SQLServerManager14.msc para SQL Server 2017

SQLServerManager13.msc para SQL Server 2016

SQLServerManager12.msc para SQL Server 2014

SQLServerManager11.msc para SQL Server 2012

SQLServerManager10.msc para SQL Server 2008

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos,